# LaTeX formatting error

Tags: formatting, right-to-left

I've converted a word document to LaTeX but when I write :

```
"BELLARE , M , ..."
```

Latex shows me:

```
"... , M , BELLERE"
```

What's the error and how to solve it?

part of text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{LectureTemplate}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}

\handout{سمینار نظریه علوم کامپیوتر}

\section{مقدمه:}

....

\section{ منابع}

{
BELLARE , M , ...
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello abdolah. In `xepersian`, to have the text left-to-right, you can surround it by `\lr{}`, or in your case, `\lr{BELLARE , M , ...}`.

Comment: @Pouya , thanks. it works. how about a long text which may contains "{" ? is there anything like \begin{(left to right...)} to work for it?

Comment: In that case you need to escape the bracket by adding ``\`` to the bracket, e.g. `\{` with produce a simple curly bracket. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\lr{}` to write left-to-right in a persian document that is right-to-left in nature.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}

\section{مقدمه:}
\section{ منابع}
یکی از روش‌های نگارش چپ به راست استفاده از
\lr{\textbackslash lr\{\}}
می‌باشد. به عنوان مثال 
\lr{\{BELLARE , M , ...\}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your left-to-right text (or anyother text for that matter) has `{`, you need to escape it by using `\`.